# Why does copying a pointer to a Go struct not stay linked to the original?

Tags: go

I was playing around with go struct and struct pointer and something of late bemused me

The example in question is this listed [here](https://play.golang.org/p/RQ_742b48Zj)

What I tried

```
    p1 := &Shirt{Price: 15.00,SKU: "empty"}
    t := *p1
    t1 := &t
```

After which I tried to change the `Price` and `SKU` for t1 expecting that it would change the eventual value of p1.

But I was surprised that a t1 had an address different from p1 or t1 was a clone of p1(Shirt) was created (i.e t1).

I believe this not the same in C (https://cplayground.com/?p=gull-lapwing-mouse)

So how is Go Internal handles this that different from other languages like C?

Comment: It's not different. `t := *p1` makes t a Shirt, not a pointer to a Shirt, so of course it's disconnected. If you wanted to copy the pointer instead of create a new object copied from the pointer's destination, you would need to leave out the `*` in that line.

Comment: So this is like in C if you used `memcpy()` in that second line to copy the pointer's destination into the location of your target struct.

Comment: Which specific line of code in your linked C program are you claiming is identical to the line `t := *p1` in Go? Please edit the shortest possible reproducer into your question itself, and call out the specific line you believe to be identical. Reading your C program at a glance, I see no equivalent code.

Answer (score 1):

Go and C are exactly the same in this case.

This is the equivalent in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Shirt {
   int    Price;
   char*  Sku;
};

int main() {
    struct Shirt s1 = {
        Price: 15,
        Sku: "empty"
    };
    struct Shirt* s2 = &s1;
    struct Shirt  s3 = *s2;
    struct Shirt* s4 = &s3;
    
    printf("s1 address = %p, s3 address = %p\n", s2, s4);
    printf("s4.Price = %d, s4.Sku = %s\n", s4->Price, s4->Sku);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Playground](https://cplayground.com/?p=cattle-coati-reindeer)

It outputs

```
s1 address = 0x7fff4201ce20, s3 address = 0x7fff4201ce30
s4.Price = 15, s4.Sku = empty
```

You would not be able to modify s1 through s4.

In Go you would have

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Shirt struct {
    Price int
    SKU string
}

func main() {
    p1 := &Shirt{Price: 15.00,SKU: "empty"}
    t := *p1
    t1 := &t

    fmt.Printf("p1 address = %p, t1 address = %p\n", p1, t1)
    fmt.Printf("t1.Price = %v, t1.SKU = %v\n", t1.Price, t1.SKU)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5pp4riudqWE)

It would output

```
p1 address = 0xc0000ac040, t1 address = 0xc0000ac060
t1.Price = 15, t1.SKU = empty
```

So Go and C would handle this scenario the same.

Comment: For starters your C example is incredibly hard to read. Don't just take my word for it, come back when you have completely forgot about it and try to read it to experience what others experience when reading it. Also it is not consistent with the Go example you provided. When you do this `struct Books *personPtr;
 struct Books *personPtr2;
 personPtr = &Book1;
 personPtr2 = &(*personPtr);` You are not creating space on the stack for a new type. You are just dereferencing a pointer and then take the address of it.  personPtr == personPtr2.

Comment: Or, a shorter version of what Steven Eckhoff said, in `personPtr2 = &(*personPtr)` the `&` and `*` cancel each other out and you've just done `personPtr2 = personPtr`.